# How to split a video file in small pieces in Dart/flutter?

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, dart

I picked a video file from local storage, i want the video file to be split into desired small parts(video files) programmatically. Can i do it in dart or i have to write code for java and swift ?

Answer (score 1):

This package may help, [ffmpeg_kit_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter):

```
 import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter/ffmpeg_kit.dart';

 FFmpegKit.executeAsync('-i file1.mp4 -c:v mpeg4 file2.mp4', (session) async {
   final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

   if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {

     // SUCCESS

   } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(returnCode)) {

     // CANCEL

   } else {

     // ERROR

   }
 });
```

for splitting video, FFmpeg command examples:

> "-i source-file.foo -ss 0 -t 600 first-10-min.m4v"
>
> "-i source-file.foo -ss 600 -t 600 second-10-min.m4v"
>
> "-i source-file.foo -ss 1200 -t 600 third-10-min.m4v"

Comment: can you write a sample function that would be really helpful

Comment: Hello @user17617805 , are you able divide video file into smaller chunks please help